# setContentPane covering everything up and JButton not working properly

Tags: java, swing

I am making a game in which a player attempts to navigate a maze, but I have run into two bugs that have absolutely stumped me. My first problem is with using `setContentPane()`. Whenever I set it to my intended background, it covers up everything else on the screen. I have tried relocating it to every place I thought it could be, but it still covered it up. My second question is about my `JButton`.  Whenever I click it, it changes to the playing speed as intended, but I can't move afterwards. It works when I use the method in my Keylistener, and they have the same code inside of them. I have included all code that I thought was necessary, but if you need any more, let me know. The full source for this project can be found [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ctb00l458en42v/src.zip?dl=0).

```
package game;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    private boolean upPressed    = false;
    private boolean downPressed  = false;
    private boolean rightPressed = false;
    private boolean leftPressed  = false;

    private int tileSize = 200;
    private int playerSize = tileSize / 4;
    private int playerSpeed = playerSize / 10;
    private int mazeX = 51;
    private int mazeY = 51;

    private int[][] maze = new int[mazeX][mazeY];
    private int[][] initX = new int[mazeX][mazeY];
    private int[][] initY = new int[mazeX][mazeY];
    private boolean[][] visited = new boolean[mazeX][mazeY];

    private int currentCellX = 0;
    private int currentCellY = 0;
    private int deltaX = 0;
    private int deltaY = 0;

    JComponent background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/assets/ui/mainMenu.png")));
    JButton adventure = new JButton();
    JButton freePlay = new JButton();
    JButton exit = new JButton();
    JButton pause = new JButton();
    JButton resume = new JButton();

    private String screen = "menu";
    public Main main;


    public Game(Main main) {
        this.main = main;

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        addButtons();
        setUpInitialCoordinates();
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000 / 120,  this);
        timer.start();
    }


    private void tick() {
        switch (screen) {
            case "playing" :
                background.setVisible(false);
                if (upPressed) {
                    deltaY += playerSpeed;
                } else if (downPressed) {
                    deltaY -= playerSpeed;
                }
                if (rightPressed) {
                    deltaX -= playerSpeed;
                } else if (leftPressed) {
                    deltaX += playerSpeed;
                }
                break;
            case "paused":
                background.setVisible(false);
                adventure.setVisible(false);
                freePlay.setVisible(false);
                pause.setVisible(false);
                exit.setVisible(true);
                break;
            case "menu":
                main.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/assets/ui/mainMenu.png"))));
                adventure.setVisible(true);
                freePlay.setVisible(true);
                pause.setVisible(false);
                exit.setVisible(true);
                break;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    private void addButtons() {
        setLayout(null);
        add(freePlay);
        freePlay.setBounds(10, 100, 180, 80);
        freePlay.setSize(180, 80);
        freePlay.setAction(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                downPressed = false;
                rightPressed = false;
                leftPressed = false;
                generateMaze();
                screen = "playing";
            }
        });
        freePlay.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/assets/ui/buttons/freePlayUnselected.png")));
        freePlay.setRolloverIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/assets/ui/buttons/freePlaySelected.png")));
    }

    private void setUpInitialCoordinates() {
    }


    private void generateMaze() {
    }


    private boolean checkForUnvisitedCells() {
    }


    private boolean checkForUnvisitedAdjacentCells() {
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tick();
    }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}


    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    }


    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you thing `setContentPane` does?  Perhaps you should have a look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html)

Comment: *"My second question is about my JButton. Whenever I click it, it changes to the playing speed as intended, but I can't move afterwards. It works when I use the method in my Keylistener"* - Welcome to the wonderful world of why you shouldn't use `KeyListener`, the button has stolen key board focus and the `KeyListener` will no longer respond to key board input because it relies on the component it is registered to be focusable AND focused.  Use key bindings instead.  [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The keyListener was the method that worked, the JButton half worked, but prevented me from moving. As for `setContentPane()` my friend told me that is how to set a background for a JFrame.

Comment: Your friend is half right.  Everything you add to a frame is added to the CURRENT content pane, this means when you change it, the old content is also "removed" along with the old content pane.  `KeyListener` is well know for it's focus related issues, when you click the button, the button will now have key board focus, meaning your `KeyListener` on your `Game` `JPanel` can no longer receive key events, this is why we don't recommend it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, thanks, I will convert my game to Key Bindings

Answer (score 1):

`setContentPane` does just that, it replaces what ever was previously been used as the content with the new component.

[image: RootPane]

Take a closer look at [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details.

I'd suggest that a better solution would be to use a `CardLayout`, but in this case, a better solution would be to just change the `icon` property of the current content pane...

```
background.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/assets/ui/mainMenu.png")));
```

and simply make the `background` the frame's content pane...

```
JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/assets/ui/mainMenu.png")));

//....
public Game(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
    setContentPane(background);
    //...
```

Then never change the content pane...

You could then use a `CardLayout` to change what appears on the content pane

> My second question is about my JButton. Whenever I click it, it changes to the playing speed as intended, but I can't move afterwards. It works when I use the method in my Keylistener

Welcome to the wonderful world of why you shouldn't use `KeyListener`, the button has stolen key board focus and the `KeyListener` will no longer respond to key board input because it relies on the component it is registered to be focusable AND focused.  Use key bindings instead.  [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: If my assumptions about this are correct, then I can't change the background after that, correct?

Comment: Yes, you can, simply change the `background`s `icon` property (as demonstrated) to what ever you want, when ever you want...